# What causes the various cartoonish sounds when starting a Model T?

Tags: ford

When the early Fords such as the Model T and Model A are being cold-started, there are a variety of unusual sounds that are not heard in modern automobiles. After the starter is run for a bit without the engine firing, there is a sound something like an orchestral ratchet. There are also puffing noises with each rotation that seem to exist only for random periods. One would imagine that it is from such early automobiles that we get cartoon-type stereotypes of old cars.

What in an old ford is mechanically different from a more modern car that would make the unusual noises?

Here is a video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1LesV4QhlM My father's restored Model A also makes similar noises when starting after a long winter.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to remove the air intake pipes and filter from a modern car you would hear the same puffing noises as the air is sucked in.  Improved silencers on the exhaust probably also remove some of the other 'cartoonish' sounds.

I will have to listen again to the video for the 'orchestral ratchet'.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reasons for old engines to make sounds that you wont hear from modern engines. Like HandyHowie noted there is almost no sound deadening so there will be more noise. Then there is the ignition timing which often needs to be retarded manually (with a lever near the steering wheel) for the engine to start. Once the engine gets up to speed the combustion will sound a bit 'off' until the timing is advanced again to its normal running setting. Also the fuel delivery system is not that advanced so the engine can have some misfires or lean strokes, especially when just started.